# HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 416 in PHP

Tags: php

I have this code which I got an error in the link line.

```
$link = file_get_contents("http://www.manta.com/search?search=store&pg=1"); 
  $file = strip_tags($link, "<span>");
  if(preg_match_all('/<span itemprop="streetAddress">(?:[^<]*)<\/span>/is', $file, $content, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER)){

  /*$final = print_r($content, true);
  echo $final;
  */
  $i = 0;
  if(!empty($content[0][$i])){ 

    while(!empty($content[0][$i])){

        echo $content[0][$i];
        $i++;
    }
  }
  }
```

the error is

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.manta.com/search?search=store&pg=1): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable on line 17.
```

I just want to get the store addresses from that site.

Comment: if it's requiring a range, then you can't do a plain f_g_c() call. you'll have to add the appropriate range header, which means setting up a stream first, or using curl.